# How to wait for a loop to finish within an api that finds an array of ids? SailsJs

Tags: javascript, sql, api, sails.js, es6-promise

I am using the find() method to look into a table in my db, which returns  a record that has a column that contains an array of ids for some users.

I would like to loop through this ids and use another find() method to return the users details.

from what I know, I have to use a promise to wait till the loop finishes. However, Im not so sure how to use the promise for my case.

this is what I have tried so far but I only get empty arrays for both console logs.

```
  getShortList : (req,res)=>{

    function shortList(ids){
      var companies = []

      for (var i = 0; i<ids.length; i++){
        await new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(()=>{
            Company.find({id:ids[i]}).exec((err,company)=>{
              if (err) return res.serverError(err)

              companies.push(company)
            })
          },5000)
          resolve(companies)

        })

    }
  }
    async function testFunc(){

    var job_type = req.body.job_type
    var job_listing_id = req.body.job_listing_id

      Supplier_job_listing.find({id:job_listing_id}).exec((err,job)=>{
        if (err) return res.serverError(err)

        var list = shortList(job[0].shortlisted_bidders_ids)
        list.then((result)=>{
          console.log('receiving it here',result)
        })


      })

  }
  testFunc();

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your complete code, but the response to your problem will be something like:

```
async function shortList(ids){
  let promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i<ids.length; i++){
    promises.push(Company.find({id:ids[i]}));
  }
  let companies = await Promise.all( promises);
  return companies;
}

function testFunc(){
  shortList()
   .then((companies) => {
     // do something with your companies
   })
   .catch(error){
     // console.log(error);
   }
}
testFunc();
```

Comment: thank you it worked fine, just needed to adjust the calling of the function to send a parameter:
shortList(ids).then((companies))=>{}

Comment: @[hussein-menshawi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9057544/hussein-menshawi): You are welcome. I am pleased to hear that.